# Cambiar de mayúsculas a minúsculas una posición de una variable char en R

Tags: r

tengo un vector que contiene variables tipo carácter, los cuales corresponden a nombres de municipios.
Alguien sabe como cambiar de minúsculas a mayúsculas sólo una letra de estas variables?

Por ejemplo: el Bruc --> El Bruc

He encontrado que la función toupper() realiza el cambio de minúscula a mayúscula, pero no se cómo seleccionar únicamente una parte de la variable.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bueno, y como esperas realizarlo? desde un Input? desde una variable almacenada en tu script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364783/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-both-words-in-a-two-word-string) pregunta tiene varias opciones interesantes para hacer lo que buscas, voy a traducir algunas de ellas:

#### Construir una función "ad-hoc"

```
v <- c('el Bruc', 'Ya capitalizado', 'otra Prueba')

firstCap <- function(x) {
    s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
    paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), 
          substring(s, 2),
          sep="", collapse=" ")
}

unlist(lapply(v, FUN=firstCap))
```

La salida:

```
[1] "El Bruc"         "Ya Capitalizado" "Otra Prueba"
```

Simplemente `firstCap` hace un split de una cadena y reemplaza el primer caracter por su versión capitalizada. Luego simplemente aplicamos la función al vector.

#### Usar expresiones regulares y `gsub()`

```
gsub("(^|[[:space:]])([[:alpha:]])", "\\1\\U\\2", v, perl=TRUE)
```

La salida es la misma que la opción anterior y lo que hace simplemente se hacer una substitución del primer carácter alpha a su versión en mayucula.

#### Usar la función base `toTitleCase`

```
library(tools)
unlist(lapply(v, FUN=toTitleCase))
```

Podemos evitar tener que construir una función usando la ya incorporada `toTitleCase`, sin embargo hay que tener en cuenta que algunas palabras en inglés no las capitaliza

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio!