# adaptar base de datos

Tags: excel, r, rstudio

Tengo una base de datos en excel de esta forma

```
letra   2000 2001 2002 
a         1     2    3
d         1     2    3
e         1     2    3
g         1     2    3
```

y tengo otra base de datos con la siguiente estructura

```
letra    2000 2001 2002
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

como puedo hacer en r o en excel para insertar los datos de la primera base en la segunda, respetando el nombre de la columna por ejemplo "2000" y los de la fila ejemplo "a"? sin tener que copiar y pegar fila por fila.
Necesito que tenga la siguiente forma:

```
letra  2000 2001 2002
a       1    2    3 
b
c
d       1    2    3
e       1    2    3
f
g       1    2    3
```

Comment: ¿El orden dado por las letras, está definido en una columna de tu excel?

Comment: no.Solo la de los años esta definido en columnas

Comment: Pero entonces como podemos saber cual es la correspondencia entre las filas de los dos `data.frames`? ¿Las letras representan los `rownames` de cada tabla?

Comment: disculpas. ahora entendí, si le puse nombre y definí las columnas de las letras. Este es un ejemplo, pero la base de datos contiene provincias y años que comprenden desde 1970 hasta 2018, los datos son de precipitaciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como lo entiendo:

```
df1= data.frame(id=c("a","d","e","g"), "2001"=rep(1,4), "2002"=rep(2,4),"2003"=rep(3,4))
df2= data.frame(id=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"), "2001"=rep(NA,7),"2002"= rep(NA,7), "2003"= rep(NA,7))
```

Buscamos las coincidencias

```
m=match(df2$id,df1$id,nomatch=0)
```

Y las reemplazamos

```
df2[m>0,]=df1
```

Lo que no sé es cómo se pone la tabla resultante en el foro. Si alguien me puede modificar mi mensaje y ponerlo, lo agradecería.

Comment: Cuando hago esto, sale este error:                                                                 In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, m > 0, , value = structure(list( ... :
  replacement element 1 has 41 rows to replace 16 rows                               
 Si tengo en una base por ejemplo A y en la otra a, hay que agregar algo mas para que se matcheen ?

Comment: Si no te cambia el resultado, puedes cambiar de mayúsculas a minúsculas para que la coincidencia sea exacta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119117/cambiar-de-may%C3%BAsculas-a-min%C3%BAsculas-una-posici%C3%B3n-de-una-variable-char-en-r

Editado: Acabo de leer tu modificación. ¿Tu problema es sólo de coincidencia?

Comment: El problema está cuando reemplazo con la linea 
`df2[m>0,]=df1`
Introduzco en la consola para que me muestre los warnings y me tira:
`1: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, m > 0, , value = structure(list( ... :
  replacement element 1 has 41 rows to replace 16 rows`
y así desde el elemento 1 hasta el 50.

Comment: Puedes copiar al menos el head del "m"? Fíjate que los números superiores a 0 estén ordenados con las coincidencias que se dan en tu conjunto de datos. Si no es así, es que no encuentra coincidencias. Entonces igual el problema es con las mayúsculas que dices.

Comment: El problema eran efectivamente las mayúsculas. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.
Solucionado

Comment: puede tambien usarse merge.data.frame() ?

Answer (score 0):

Tambien se puede utilizar merge.data.frame() y luego eliminamos los datos que se repiten con distinct de dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

dat = merge.data.frame(df1,df2,by = "letra", all.y =  TRUE,sort = TRUE)
dat = distinct(dat, letra, .keep_all= TRUE)
```